# Kludge to trick SE to allow edits smaller than six characters by injecting invisible characters

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

It's impossible to fix small (but not insignificant) typos on SE without making other edits adding up to six characters. For example, *think* should be *thi**c**k* in a quoted line of a poem that makes no sense if it says "think".

Could invisible characters be injected, perhaps at the bottom of the post?
[⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀]

Comment: If a typo is really the only thing that needs fixed, it would be better to leave a comment for the author than suggest an edit. Even if the author doesn't see it, someone with editing privileges might. Unnecessary fiddling to bypass the trivial edit threshold are worse than an obvious typo.

Comment: @ColleenV, **why** is that better? One person leaving a comment, and another person the reading the comment and doing the actual editing, takes more time in total than it would take for one persons to just do it right away.

Comment: Apologies. I tried to change 3 letters and get the error message, which I didn't. My idea was to work around your challenge without a trick: Change a whole word when only one letter is really off. That edit is actually easiest to read later. Now if moderators could remove both edits, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who's a low-rep editor on other sites, I sympathize. But, as someone who's [reviewing this type of edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (both here and elsewhere), hacks like these are kinda annoying.

There is a little bit of leeway built in. For questions, changing the title even by a single character will lift the limit for the body text ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/86811)). Titles are important: Make sure it's good!

As for other edits, is there really nothing more to do with the post? There are some posts here that might be the pinnacle of writing (except for single character typos, apparently), but usually that's not the case. A lot of people waffle ("so, actually"), a lot of people fluff ("thanks in advance!"), a lot of people over-tense (past perfect when past is fine). This is your opportunity to make minor changes, even substitute out a slightly informal word for a more formal synonym.

See also: [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520/323179)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose there's good reason not to do this if someone else has to clean it up. But the rules on SE often seem arbitrary.

Comment: I would be in favor of lowering the character limit on sites like this where there's not too many edits, but unfortunately I've never heard of this being customized so I don't think it would be done.

Comment: Well, it could be a double edit. Invisible characters to permit the edit, and then edit again to remove the invisible characters :-)  Or do you then see **two** edits that you have to review ??

Comment: While it's possible to edit your suggested edit after submission (and before it's handled), I think it's still checked against the current live revision, so you would get the same error. (You could test this [in the sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/323179) by suggesting edits while logged out.)

Comment: This.  An unfortunate issue usually flagged in suggested edits obvious for rejection (i.e. attempt to reply: "Yes!  This!") is people deleting and retyping (not sure if it's actually copy paste) parts of the answer to meet the quota.  If push really comes to shove on a typo and that's the only thing you think you can improve, you're not looking hard enough.

Comment: "If ...that's the only thing you think you can improve, you're not looking hard enough" makes me want to use language that would get me banned.  I want to fix one important thing, not tidy up. The corner of the carpet near the fireplace is on fire. I don't want to dust the end-tables in order to be able to put the fire out.

Comment: @Tim Correcting a single character typo that anyone fluent in English can recognize as a typo is not an urgent enough fix that it needs to go in the suggested edit queue. If it significantly damages the ability to understand the post, you should be asking the author to clarify. If it doesn't affect the clarity of the post, leave it for someone who has earned the editing privilege or who is willing to make more significant improvements. It's that simple.

Comment: @Tim I thank you for keeping the house from burning down because as someone whose cooking means keeping the battery out of the smoke alarm, surely I will choke in my sleep.  Let's all be partners on this.  As I reiterated what Laurel said about such edits, it's also true that one typo correction can bump an old question unnecessarily and make others harder to see.  Make sure it's worth it; you're not alone with the dusting and the drawing of the drapes when the dressed chicken is burning.

Comment: It is somewhat unclear here whether Laurel and @livresque are **(1) defending** the 6-characted limitation as something reasonable, **or (2) expressing resignation** to it (with the attitude 'This is something imposed on us from above, and there is nothing we can do to change it, so we may as well make the best of it').

Comment: @jsw29 I can only speak for myself: The limit isn't really useful on a site like this where the edit queue isn't filling up, but I'm not sure if it can be changed. Otherwise I would suggest a lower limit — at least on a trial basis.

Comment: @ColleenV This site baffles me. You have or do not have editing privileges, right? But a single typo, as it now stands, cannot be edited. OK. But then what does this mean? "Leave it for someone who has earned the editing privilege."

Comment: @Lambie The privilege is to edit without peer review. Anyone may suggest an edit as long as it is more than 6 characters. If the edit is approved, you earn a token amount of reputation. once you’ve earned the privilege to bypass the suggested edit queue, you can make single character edits immediately, but stop getting rep for them. https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: @ColleenV On ELU and ELL, I edit because I have the privilege. But I have tried single letter edits and have found they do not work. I dunno. Maybe I am mixed up. Everything is so complicated it seems. I will tell you that I do not understand  half of all these discussions on metas. This one and others.

Comment: @Lambie Maybe I’m confused and was able to do things because I was a mod? I rarely bother with such small edits, so it’s possible.

Comment: @ColleenV Right. Point taken. :)